# Clicking a link programmatically after using preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, click, dom-events, preventdefault

I'm trying to change a href link programmatically (according to a result from an ajax async operation) and open it in a new window (I don't want to use window.open as it behaves like a popup and being blocked in IE).

The following code works only after clicking MANUALLY on the link for a second time, how can I make it work on the first click?

Simplified example:

```
    <a href="http://demo.com" id="link">trying to change href link dynamically</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('link').addEventListener("click", function (e) {

                if (!e.target.hasAttribute("target")) //only preventDefault for the first time..
            {
                    e.target.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    updateLink();
                    }
            });

            function updateLink() {
// --HERE I PERFORM AN AJAX CALL WHICH TAKES A WHILE AND BY ITS RESULT I DECIDE WHICH URL TO USE - BUT HERE I JUST USE IT HARDCODED--
                document.getElementById('link').setAttribute("href", "http://google.com");
                document.getElementById('link').click();
            }
```

Comment: code blocks that long should be jsfiddled

Comment: Maybe silly, but have you tried simpling calling the `click()` function twice?

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: @Erik Christianson - Tried that with no luck. poodle - I use IE10.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `window.location.href = "<chosen url>"`?

Comment: @Bergi - because I want to open the link in another window/tab and not instead of the current page

Comment: @BornToCode: Then it would be `window.open()`. But you can't call this from ajax, as it would be blocked like a popup then - it must be triggered from an user event.

Answer (score 1):

I organized your code in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mswieboda/Hhj4D/

The JavaScript:

```
var $link = document.getElementById('link');
$link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (!e.target.hasAttribute("target")) {
        //only preventDefault for the first time..
        e.target.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        e.preventDefault();
        updateLink();
    }
});

function updateLink() {
    $link.setAttribute("href", "http://google.com");
    $link.click();
}
```

This worked for me when I ran it. Hovering the link, you could see `http://demo.com` but clicking it takes you to `http://google.com`. Is this the desired functionality? You can definitely use the updateLink function any time (after an AJAX call) to change the `href`, also, you could probably set the `_target` in that function as well, makes more sense to me that way.